# Optimize a sorting while loop

Tags: r, optimization, while-loop

I have been working on a variation of a traveling salesman problem.  The solution I am trying to implement is to load my vehicle as close to the max as possible as return trips are largely expensive.

I have a large data set in the following format:

```
pkgid   Latitude    Longitude   Weight
42127   8.205561907 34.54574863 37.0660242
42069   7.640153828 34.03634169 31.91148072
96632   7.700233671 33.85385033 24.27309403
93160   7.756960678 35.36007723 22.3526782
39075   6.881522479 34.19903152 19.56993506
62579   7.622385316 33.78590124 16.7793145
93784   7.523606197 35.32735063 16.18484202
81204   7.597161645 33.81316073 11.54433538
```

My solution is to take the farthest point south and grab nearby neighbours until my vehicle is full.  I have a code snippet that works, but very slow (seconds per loop).  I could use a kmeans or similar method, but there is no good way to guarantee a full load or cut off clustering with a metric (that I know of).  So I wrote my own.

```
##NN Algorithm
pkg <- data.frame(fread("muh_data"))
pkg$TripId=0
NN<-data.frame(setorder(pkg,Latitude))
loc<-1
weight<-0
current_point<-c(NN[1,3],NN[1,2])
TripID=1

while (dim(NN)[1]>0)
{
    while ((weight<1000)&(dim(NN)[1]>0)){
    NN<-NN[-c(loc),]
    if(dim(NN)[1]==0)
    {break}
    NN$NN<-distHaversine(current_point,cbind(NN$Longitude,NN$Latitude))
    loc<-which.min(NN$NN)
    current_point=c(NN[loc,3],NN[loc,2])
    whichpkg<-NN[loc,1]
    if ((weight+pkg[loc,4]>1000)|(dim(NN)[1])==0){
    break}
    weight=weight+pkg[loc,4]
    pkg[pkg$pkgid==whichpkg,5]<-TripID
    }
print(TripID) ##just a visual check where I am at--should end at ~3500
TripID=TripID+1
weight=0
loc<-1
}
```

Any hints for speeding this up?

Comment: R is very useful, but not necessarily for performance of of such user-written algorithms. I would write it in C or C++ and shell out to it from R. Also, traveling-salesman type problems are not not easy to find optimal solutions to, but *good* solutions are not difficult to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first use the profiler (Rprof) to find where time is being spent.  next try to replace dataframes with matrices -- dataframes are very slow when accessing. then you might know where to focus.

Comment: It does look like the distHaversine and writes are consuming a bit of time.  As one of the comments suggested, it may be time to do some optimization is C.  Rprof turns out be be a nice do it yourself diagnostic.  Switching to matrices didn't save a lot of time, but at least it helps me peak under the hood.